# How can I use images as numbers/letters in Android?

Tags: android, fonts, android-image

I am developing an app where I need to show a count. This count is going to show for example a "4", then a "4 + 1", then finally a "5". I have .png images that I want to use as background to the numbers, so that I can easily show anything up to "99" if I need to.

So basically, I would like to assign a drawable background to a number. Is a custom font the way to go? H[ere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084659/how-to-set-numbers-as-images-on-textview) typeface and view group with assigned strings is mentioned. Anyone tried this?

Comment: My problem is exactly as yours (link you provided), want to use images as numbers. Still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you just need an array of size 10:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable numbers = new Drawable[10]{
   new Drawable(res, R.drawable.zero),
   new Drawable(res, R.drawable.one),
   new Drawable(res, R.drawable.two),
   ...
   new Drawable(res, R.drawable.nine)
};
```

and to get them just use:

```
int i = 5;
Drawable image = numbers[i];
```

If the number has 2 digits then you can put in 2 pictures etc.

You can also make a very big array, but that would honestly be a waste of lines.
Also the space required when you only use 10 pictures is significantly smaller

Comment: Hi! I used this, with a tweak:  int[] numbers = {R.drawable.zero,
    R.drawable.one,
   R.drawable.four2x,
   ...
  R.drawable.nine2x
  };
  Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(numbers[0]);  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<char, Drawable> charMap = new HashMap(Character, Drawable>();
Resources res = getResources();
charMap.put('0', new Drawable(res, R.drawable.img_0));
charMap.put('1', new Drawable(res, R.drawable.img_1));
// the rest of the characters you want to use
```

When you want to retrieve the correct image for a character:

```
char c = '0';
Drawable charImage = charMap.get(c);
```